# Could any of you explain how many Google search engines actually are?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, search

Could any of you explain ( or any of you knows) how many Google search engines actually are? In my country ( POLAND) they used to teach us we ought to always use www.google.com....that would be per definition world wide search which nowadays isn't at all...

In other countries it was possible to access webites on internet such as [www.google.nl](http://www.google.nl) ( for the Netherlands), [www.google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk) ( for UK), [www.google.ie](http://www.google.ie) ( for Ireland )and so on ...

Is it true that each country has its own google or is it some network that has been developed?

Although I pay for internet ( Polish internet provider) I do not get search results from other countries. Of course There is always info on The net claiming that Google has problem to understand the language...or its a matter of localisation but I personally don't believe it because I have tried many other search engines and different devices, however I always get same irrelevant search results.

For instance,  if I were in Itally and have search "otto" which mean eight (8) I would get many relevant search results refering to eight (8) , unfortunatelly from Polish internet network provider I get results only from marketing ( sales), some other stupid few website links , however competelly nothing refering to number 8.
More than that, I do not rely on The information from that network claiming google search engine does not recognise the language while same Time they have google.translate that is able to detect the language with no problem.
Does any of you have idea where the problem comes from?
Is that something about internet provider network or devices such as mobiles or laptops?

Actually most of the search results seems to be some poor resource limited to few websites ( 10 ...Highest 20) while from internet cafes I used to have plenty more search results.

Another thing would be The questions like is it possible that we are cut of some routers that ought to get search results from other countries? Or maybe something they have as simillar to intranet instead of real internet connection?

Comment: Google does appear to detect the language that your browser is set for, and possibly uses that information and/or your IP address to decide what results to show you and which Google site to redirect you to (I've tried to use google.de from the US to do a German-language search, and been redirected to google.com and English-language results). I don't consider it likely that there are multiple search engines, just filtering of the results based on language and (possibly) geography.

Comment: I don't think that this question is opinion-based. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Google tries, for efficiency reasons, to connect you to its
nearest node, in order to shorten your interaction time
with the server and make a good impression of being speedy.
But also in order to distribute the workload among all its
servers. This is based more on the region than on the country.

Forcing `google.com` is not always successful, but when it
works the interface language will be in English and it
would prioritize posts written in English in the
returned answers.

This is the list of
[Google supported domains](https://www.google.com/supported_domains).
There are 187 servers in the list, and 195 countries in the world.
Large countries may have more than one server, and small
countries may use a neighbor's server
(especially if they use the same language).

> .google.com .google.ad .google.ae .google.com.af .google.com.ag .google.al .google.am .google.co.ao .google.com.ar .google.as .google.at .google.com.au .google.az .google.ba .google.com.bd .google.be .google.bf .google.bg .google.com.bh .google.bi .google.bj .google.com.bn .google.com.bo .google.com.br .google.bs .google.bt .google.co.bw .google.by .google.com.bz .google.ca .google.cd .google.cf .google.cg .google.ch .google.ci .google.co.ck .google.cl .google.cm .google.cn .google.com.co .google.co.cr .google.com.cu .google.cv .google.com.cy .google.cz .google.de .google.dj .google.dk .google.dm .google.com.do .google.dz .google.com.ec .google.ee .google.com.eg .google.es .google.com.et .google.fi .google.com.fj .google.fm .google.fr .google.ga .google.ge .google.gg .google.com.gh .google.com.gi .google.gl .google.gm .google.gr .google.com.gt .google.gy .google.com.hk .google.hn .google.hr .google.ht .google.hu .google.co.id .google.ie .google.co.il .google.im .google.co.in .google.iq .google.is .google.it .google.je .google.com.jm .google.jo .google.co.jp .google.co.ke .google.com.kh .google.ki .google.kg .google.co.kr .google.com.kw .google.kz .google.la .google.com.lb .google.li .google.lk .google.co.ls .google.lt .google.lu .google.lv .google.com.ly .google.co.ma .google.md .google.me .google.mg .google.mk .google.ml .google.com.mm .google.mn .google.com.mt .google.mu .google.mv .google.mw .google.com.mx .google.com.my .google.co.mz .google.com.na .google.com.ng .google.com.ni .google.ne .google.nl .google.no .google.com.np .google.nr .google.nu .google.co.nz .google.com.om .google.com.pa .google.com.pe .google.com.pg .google.com.ph .google.com.pk .google.pl .google.pn .google.com.pr .google.ps .google.pt .google.com.py .google.com.qa .google.ro .google.ru .google.rw .google.com.sa .google.com.sb .google.sc .google.se .google.com.sg .google.sh .google.si .google.sk .google.com.sl .google.sn .google.so .google.sm .google.sr .google.st .google.com.sv .google.td .google.tg .google.co.th .google.com.tj .google.tl .google.tm .google.tn .google.to .google.com.tr .google.tt .google.com.tw .google.co.tz .google.com.ua .google.co.ug .google.co.uk .google.com.uy .google.co.uz .google.com.vc .google.co.ve .google.co.vi .google.com.vn .google.vu .google.ws .google.rs .google.co.za .google.co.zm .google.co.zw .google.cat

Comment: Thank you for the information and The answer. Actually, i have tried Both google.com and Google.it ( which as far as I know is for Italy), however I get irrelevant search results (mainly online shops or Polish advertisers). In fact all search results are same despite the fact which search engine or internet network I use. All search web results do not refer to what otto or could be compared to the search results from italian network. Can you explain what it exactly indicates or means?

Comment: It's hard to force Google to give answers that are not oriented to your region. Even if you use a server from some region, Google can use you IP address to localize your region and prioritize local information. Setting English as your preferred language helps in general. But it's always a fight that changes as the Google site evolves. Alternative search engines might be less invasive.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly I do not get refered to any option of giving you marking as accepted on this platform side at all.

Comment: The ✔ icon is found to the left of my answer.